Filtering nested objects using JQ
For a given json:
{
  "source_1": [
    {
      "val1": "foo1",
      "val2": "bar1"
    },
    {
      "val1": "foo2",
      "val2": "bar2"
    }
  ],
  "source_2": [
    {
      "val1": "foo1",
      "val2": "bar1"
    },
    {
      "val1": "foo3",
      "val2": "bar3"
    }
  ]
}

I would like to search it recursively where val2 equals bar1 but return it in this format:
{
  "source_1": [
    {
      "val1": "foo1",
      "val2": "bar1"
    }
  ],
  "source_2": [
    {
      "val1": "foo1",
      "val2": "bar1"
    }
  ]
}


This produces your expected output:
map_values(map(select(.val2 == "bar1")))

Online demo
